# Launchpad icons not showing NSDockTile badge anymore

Tags: macos, cocoa

Launchpad icons (except for Apple's apps) are not showing the NSDockTile badge anymore (since 10.8.1 or 10.8.2) does anyone know what's up with that and how to make badges show on Launchpad icons again ?

I can't find any API changes for presumably specific Launchpad support in case it changed with 10.8.0 , tho i can swear it was working on 10.8 GM the same as it was in 10.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that now only Apps signed with a Developer ID certificate or from the Mac App Store show their badge on the LaunchPad icon, previously all apps did even those signed with a development certificate.