# Set Cocoa App Icon in Launchpad Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, launchpad

I want to change Mac App icon in Launchpad programmatically, just like OS X Calendar app, which shows current date in Launchpad. But I can't find any document/resource online.

I tried changing Dock icon like this:

```
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"dockIcon2.png"];
[NSApp setApplicationIconImage:image];
```

But this only changes Dock icon, not Launchpad icon.

Is there a way to change (Mac) app icon in Launchpad programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your application signed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324902/launchpad-icons-not-showing-nsdocktile-badge-anymore

Comment: @duskwuff Hi, I saw that post before. That topic is about showing a badge in Launchpad, not changing icon. But for your question, my app is signed, both for debug and release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. App Icons have to be set when the app is compiled

Comment: So, it is like iOS calendar app, Apple has some private API, or root privilege to change icon, but other developers cannot?

Comment: Correct. That is the case